# “java.lang.ClassNotFoundException” when executing Java code when running in terminal

Tags: java, oracle, ubuntu, jdbc, terminal

I am trying run a basic code for Jdbc on my linux terminal.I have sqlplus installed.The version is Oracle 11.2.0.2.Everytime i run the code i get the following errors:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
at jdbcdisplay.main(jdbcdisplay.java:17)
```

Now i have seen the other questions asked here and most of them are connecting to Jdbc drivers using Eclipse and downloading the the jar file seems enough.But if i had to run it in the terminal how would i do it?Would i have to download http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html or is other any other way i can do it.My code is as follows:

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.SQLException;

class jdbcdisplay
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Connection conn=null;

    try
    {
        String driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
        Class.forName(driver);

        System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
        String jdbcUrl="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl";
        String user="Sourajyoti";
        String password="Sourajyoti7";

        conn=DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl,user,password);
        Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();
        String sql="SELECT ENAME,SAL,HIREDATE FROM EMP";
        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);

        while (rs.next())
        {
            String name=rs.getString("ENAME");
            double salary=rs.getDouble(2);
            Date date=rs.getDate("HIREDATE");
            System.out.print("Name: "+name);
            System.out.print("Salary: "+salary);
            System.out.println("Hiredate: "+date);
        }

        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        conn.close();
    }
    catch(SQLException se)
    {
        se.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            if (conn!=null)
                conn.close();
        }
        catch(SQLException se)
        {
            se.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("GoodBye!!");
}
}
```

Comment: How are you running this code? You need to add the drivers to the _classpath_.

Comment: Ok but i don't know how to add it to the terminal.I am not using any IDE

Comment: @Paku: You have a `-classpath` argument for the interpreter to add some directory/zip/jar to the class path.

Comment: Yes but which jar file or zip file?

Comment: The jar file(s) containing the class `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` and its dependencies (which you may need to download first).

Comment: Yes and so i went to the link specified but then which jar file should i download and how to set it up?

Comment: The file to download depends on your version of the database software and the java version and whether you want to have trace symbols in the driver. The setup procedure should be explained in some manual. To use the file, just put it to some location you can access with the interpreter and set the path accordingly using `-classpath` (or an environment variable named, IIRC, `CLASSPATH`).